# Defining integration on analytic subvarieties

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold, and let $V$ be an analytic subvariety. In books like *Griffiths-Harris: Principles of algebraic geometry*, they authors freely integrate differential forms on $V$, without caring about whether it is well-defined. For example, in page 140, it says

"Recall also that for any analytic subvariety $V$ of dimension $k$, we have defined the *fundamental class* $(V)\in H_{2k}(X,\mathbb{R})$ to be given by the linear functional $\varphi\mapsto\int_{V}\varphi$ on $H_{DR}^{2k}(X)$..."

1) It's not clear to me how the integration is defined; as far as I know, integration can be defined on manifolds or chains, but I'm not sure how to define it on a closed subset, since pullback on a closed subset doesn't make sense (I guess, right?). Does one do it by covering the closed subset by charts, and then taking partition of unity subordinate to an open cover containing the charts? Or is there some other way of defining it? Can one define it in general for any closed bounded subset, or are analytic subvarieties special?

2) Also, at least for $\mathbb {R}^n$ by a theorem due to Lebesgue, a bounded continuous function on a bounded subset $A$ is integrable as long as boundary of $A$ has measure zero; but I'm not sure whether the same is true for an analytic subvariety. (Sorry for this vague question; here I'm just trying to find a connection between the theory on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and manifolds in general).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integration on $V$ is defined in p.31-32 of the book. Indeed,

$$\int_V \phi := \int_{V^*} \phi$$

where $V^*$ is the set of smooth locus of $V$. The definition of smooth locus is given in p. 20.

For the fundamental class $[V] \in H_{2k}(M, \mathbb R)$: Define the linear mapping by

$$\tag{1} \phi \mapsto \int_V \phi$$

The Stokes theorem for analytic subvariety (p. 33) states that

$$\int _V d\psi = 0,$$

thus (1) descends to a map

$$ \int_V : H^{2k}(M, \mathbb R) \to \mathbb R$$

this linear mapping defines, via Poincare duality, an element in $H_{2k}(M, \mathbb R)$ and is denoted $[V]$.